# Unable to create Login in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have following setup:

- 2 Windows Server 2016 nodes in cluster with active-active cluster in Azure (by using s2d).
- SQL Server 2016. 2 SQL Server FCI are installed as named instances with port numbers 5011 and 5012.

Everything works as expected except when I try to create any login in SQL Server while connected from any other box except local.

I have tried using '`SQL network name\instancename,port#`' or '`sql network name fqdn\instancename,port#`'.

I keep getting below error message:

> The program cannot open the required dialog box because it cannot determine whether the computer named XXXX is joined to a domain. Close this message, and try again

Comment: Below is the error in application log  DCOM was unable to communicate with the computer xxxx using any of the configured protocols; requested by PID     1284 (C:\Windows\system32\ServerManager.exe).

Comment: Have your Network\Firewall team open up Ports 5001 & 5002 ( SMB traffic ).. Read article: https://learningintheopen.org/2016/12/15/sql-server-ssms-creating-new-credentials-error-cannot-determine-whether-computer-is-joined-to-a-domain/

Comment: That solved my problem...I have added the port 445 to two ILBs ...Thanks alot

Comment: In case this helps anyone else, I got the same error message. I was able to add users when logged in to the database with a local account (via SQL Server authentication), but not when I was logged in to the database with a domain account (via Windows authentication).